# How to extract a word between two symbols in shell script

Tags: search, grep, find, character, extract

I have a line

```
MOD record for (Batch Upload Base Interest Slab Version: Online Services) Appl: GU
```

I need to print Batch Upload Base Interest Slab Version .

```
Starting string (
End string :
```

How do i achieve this. Pls help

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can make it

```sh
awk -F"[(:]" '{print $2}'
```

- `-F"[(:]"` sets the delimiters to be either `:` or `(` (happy face!).

#### Test

```
$ echo "MOD record for (Batch Upload Base Interest Slab Version: Online Services) Appl: GU" | awk -F"[:(]" '{print $2}'
Batch Upload Base Interest Slab Version
```

Comment: ;~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
; MOD record for (Batch Upload Base Interest Slab Version: Online Services) Appl: GU
;~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
MOD
BUBISV
U
Batch Upload Base Interest Slab Version
http://$W/$A/ batch &mode=&ucid=Genupld
C
26 999
BT TT FT MT
FINW
M
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
C


I have the above file. When i tried to apply as wat u hav told, it worked , but additional line was also present. I need only that particular line what i have mentioned. Pls help .

Comment: ;~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
; MOD record for (Batch Upload Base Interest Slab Version: Online Services) Appl: GU
;~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
MOD
BUBISV
U
Batch Upload Base Interest Slab Version
http://$W/$A/ batch &mode=&ucid=Genupld
C
26 999
BT TT FT MT
FINW
M
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
C

Comment: Please update your question if your have further details to be solved. If it is a new thing, ask a new question. It is quite hard to read code in comments.

Comment: Did it solve your problem, @user2519862 ? Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted if your problem is already solved. You can do it clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$ input=(Batch Upload Base Interest Slab Version: Online Services) Appl: 
$ startString=${x#*(}
$ outputstring=${y%:*}
$ echo $outputstring
```

Comment: In this case , we are getting the input and processing for this. how do i achieve this in generic for all the files. Say for eg., there are 100 of files. I need to print the text, that is present after ( and before : in a file.

Comment: Try to use $ grep -Po or $ sed -n , use regex